# Как правильно оформить switch, содержащий noreturn-функцию?

Tags: c++, c++17

В одной из ветвей `switch-case` содержится вызов невозвратной функции (перезагрузка устройства), которая не помечена атрибутом `[[noreturn]]`. Она библиотечная (ОСРВ МАКС). Вот фрагмент кода:

```
ALARM_ACTION MyApp::OnAlarm(ALARM_REASON reason)
{
    switch (reason)
    {
    case AR_STACK_OVERFLOW:
        return AA_RESTART_TASK;
    case AR_NMI_RAISED:
    case AR_HARD_FAULT:
        System::McuReset();  //Фактически - noreturn, но не помечена атрибутом
        //?
    default:
        return Application::OnAlarm(reason);    
    }
}
```

Собственно, что написать на месте вопроса? Если написать `break`, то будет предупреждение "Не все ветви кода возвращают значение". Если не писать ничего, то будет предупреждение статического анализатора о fallthrough. Можно, конечно, написать здесь атрибут `[[fallthrough]]`, но это неправда. А как тогда правильно?

Comment: Если вы точно знаете, что программа работает правильно, то просто игнорируете предупреждения. Или поставьте после вызова функции return c каким-нибудь кодом возврата - просто чтобы не было предупреждений - вы то знаете, что до него выполнение кода никогда не дойдет.

Comment: `exit(1);` со всеми сообщениями

Comment: [`std::unreachable();`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/unreachable)?

Comment: @wololo, да, находил такую штуку. Только когда её ещё внедрят в компиляторы...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Заворачивается в функцию, которая реально noreturn:

```
[[noreturn]] void MyMcuReset(void)
{
    System::McuReset();
    ::std::abort();
}
```

И потом вызывается она:

```
case AR_HARD_FAULT: MyMcuReset();
```

Answer (score 2):

Еще вариант - добавить туда `return`, например `return {};`.